# Probability of drawing any 4 first after that any of clubs

Tags: probability

Standard 52 cards deck, calculate the probability of drawing any 4 AND after that any of clubs.

My first intuition is this, there are two possibilities: a) drawing a non clubs 4; or b) drawing a clubs 4, after that you just deduct the card from the deck, so you get:

a) 3/52 * 13/51
b) 1/52 * 12/51

But in the classroom this was resolved as:

a) 4/52 * 13/51
b) 4/52 * 12/51

I don't understand the rationale behind this, is it right/wrong?

Comment: Well if you have a 52 card deck you have a 100% probability of having four 4s and 13 clubs.  How many cards are you dealt?

Comment: Supposedly 2, I mean you pick 2 cards, first should be a 4, then a clubs, may be I should rephrase the question.

Comment: Do you have to pick the 4 before the club?  Why can't you pick the club first.  And does having the 4 of clubs and the jack of diamonds count as a success.

Comment: No, should be any 4 and then  any clubs, in that order.

Comment: You should really specify the rules in the post.  These rules are very unusual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of drawing first a non-club 4 and then a club is $3/52*13/51$.  The probability of drawing first the 4 of clubs and then a club is $1/52*12/51$.  So the probability of drawing first a 4 and then a club is $3/52*13/51 + 1/52*12/51 = 51/52*51 = 1/52$

I don't understand the second set of equations but maybe it is something like this.

The odds of drawing first a 4 is 4/52.  Then having drawn a four the probability of drawing a club is 13/51 if the 4 wasn't a club (and theres a 3/4 chance of that) or 12/51 if the 4 was a club (and there's a 1/4 chance of that.)

So the probability is $4/52(1/4*12/51 + 3/4*13/52) = 4/52*4*51(12 + 39) = 51/52*51 = 1/52$

Comment: I guess the entire purpose of this rather odd exercise was to get something where the probability is exactly 1/52.

Comment: Yeah, I'm tempted to mark this as the answer, but, since I'm not used to this kind of problems I'll wait for someone else to upvote your answer then I'll mark it, by the way, what's the probability of your answer not being the correct answer :P?

Comment: You're right, here is another one for reference: 1110101001 (http://math.stackexchange.com/users/87845/1110101001), Why is the probability of drawing a king and then a heart the same as drawing the king of hearts?, URL (version: 2014-04-15): http://math.stackexchange.com/q/755289

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean that two cards are drawn, the probability of drawing both a $4$ and a club is the sum of two cases: (a) the 4 of clubs is drawn, along with any other card; or (b) a club is drawn and a 4 is drawn, neither of which is the 4 of clubs.  The probability of (a) is
$$
p_a = \frac{1}{52} \cdot 2=\frac{1}{26}, 
$$
while the probability of (b) is
$$
p_b = \frac{12}{52} \cdot \frac{3}{51} \cdot 2 = \frac{6}{221}.
$$
Neither of these answers look like either of the answers you gave.

---

Since the question has changed, I'll add an updated answer.  The question now asks for the probability of drawing *first* a 4 and *then* a club.  The probability that the first card is the 4 of the clubs and the second is some other club is
$$
p_a = \frac{1}{52}\cdot\frac{12}{51}.
$$
The probability that the first card is a 4 of some other suit and the second is any club is
$$
p_b = \frac{3}{52}\cdot\frac{13}{51}.
$$
Putting these together gives
$$
p_a + p_b = \frac{12 + 39}{51\cdot 52}=\frac{1}{52}.
$$

Comment: You draw one first, then the other, not both at the same time

Comment: And if you must draw the 4 first and then the clubs and even if the first card is the four of clubs you must still draw a club second, then the first set of answers seems correct.  I don't understand the rationale of the second.

Comment: First should be a 4 next one a clubs.

Comment: Yeah, first should be a 4 even a 4 of clubs, then you need another one, any of clubs